# Is there a way to read unity console outside of unity?

Tags: unity, console, error-management

my unity  project keeps crashing and it does not let me read the exception error, I am wondering if there is a way to read the unity console externally outside of unity. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to do a quick search - [here's the top result for "Unity Editor Log"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html)

> ### Log Files
>
> There might be times during development when you need to obtain information from the logs of the standalone player you’ve built, the target device, or the Editor. Usually you need to see these files when you have experienced a problem, to find out exactly where the problem occurred.
>
> On macOS, the player and Editor logs can be accessed uniformly through the standard Console.app utility.
>
> On Windows, the Editor logs are placed in folders which are not shown in the Windows Explorer by default. See below.
>
> **Editor**
>
> To view the Editor log, select Open Editor Log in Unity’s Console window.

```
OS         Log files
macOS      ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
Windows    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
```

> On macOS, all the logs can be accessed uniformly through the standard Console.app utility.
>
> On Windows, the Editor log file is stored in the local application data folder \Unity\Editor\Editor.log, where  is defined by CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA.
>
> **Player**

```
OS      Log files
macOS   ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log
Windows C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\ProductName\output_log.txt
Linux   ~/.config/unity3d/CompanyName/ProductName/Player.log
```